# библиотека Pillow модуль get_on_pixels как использовать?

Tags: python-3.x, pillow

подскажите как использовать в Pillow модуль get_on_pixels не получается вообще документацию уже в доль и поперёк прочитал гуглил и бестолку сижу уже пару дней одна и та же проблема может направление подскажете а лучше рабочий пример вот ссылка да документацию:
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageMorph.html?highlight=match

img = Image.open('grayscale.png')

Comment: А что вы пытаетесь с помощью этой функции сделать?

Comment: Получить координаты пикселей нужного цвета